# Angular Cli and Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to use angular 2 in my project (note angular 4 is not approved in my company yet so can't use it). Also, want to use Angular-CLI to generate and create angular code. At the moment, angular-cli by default uses angular4 and I don't want that. Is it possible to use angular-cli to install angluar2 version?

Thanks.

Comment: Generate new project and replace angular and ts versions. It should work. But i don't understand why your company disallows angular4.

Comment: if this doesn't work - find the latest version of angular-lci that officially supported angular 2 and install it.

Comment: @ Julia: Thanks but I can't seem to find any link or previous angular2 supported versions on the website. Do you have a link for it?.

Comment: @Angad Angular team stopped *versioning* Angular in the names. Basically, there is no more *Angular 2* nor *Angular 4*: There is only **Angular**. So, technically, you can install and use **Angular** that will have parts of version **2** and other parts of version **4**.

Comment: I know that some companies can be very restrictive, but really ... I upgraded a large app (+6 months dev) in 5mn. Differences are at core level, not for angular users directly ;)

Comment: @yurzui: I generated new project using latest angular-cli and then tried to replace @angular/*  to versions as "<4.0.0" thinking that it will install less than 4 version. But when I run it I get all sorts of dependency issues. Are there any steps or links I can follow to convert angular4 to angluar2 project using latest CLI?

Comment: As SrAxi said, it's pure semver. You should just go with version 4

Comment: @Maxime: The problem is that it has not gone through the approval process so can't use it and it takes long time to do it.

Comment: Just tried it and it works http://take.ms/zlxeQ

Comment: @yurzui: Thanks that worked. I was missing router, zone and typescript versions and that is why I was getting dependency issues. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can, but you will have to work with one of the latest betas of angular-cli.

As far as I see you could use angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.32 which will install 2.4

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/v1.0.0-beta.32

Answer (score 0):

For installation steps use windows PowerShell (Run as admin) than normal command prompt  to avoid permission issues.

o   Node install 
•   Make sure you have updated node installed .At least 6.1.If yes ,skip this step. If no please download latest from https://nodejs.org/en/
•   After installation check node version node -v. And it should be 6.1 at least

o   Npm upgrade
•   After node installed check npm version npm -v
•   At least 4.4 should be present .If yes ,skip this step. If no please upgrade it using below commands and select 4.4 from the menu

   Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
   npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
   npm-windows-upgrade

•   Now check version npm -v . It should be 4.4 now

o   Angular CLI set up 
•   Once npm is ready then install angular CLI using below command 
   npm -g install angular-cli@latest  (installing globally .So no need to point any folder in cmd prompt)
•   If u have already installed angular CLI .please run below command to get updated version .

   npm uninstall -g angular-cli
   npm cache clean
   npm install -g angular-cli@latest

•   Once done please check angular cli version using ng -v . At least 1.0.0-beta.24 should be present.

•   App creation 
 We can create app using command prompt and IDE's. Currently Intellij supporting angular CLI to create angular 2 app. So for other domain developers we have to go with command prompt .

o   Create angular 2 app (Command prompt) 
•   Create some brand new project folder in your system .That will be treated as your project folder 
•   Point to that in windows normal command prompt (No need of PowerShell).
•   Run this command ng init. Will take good time to complete. Make sure you are pointed to your project folder before run this cmd.
•   It will create project structure and download all the basic dependencies to run the angular 2 app.
•   After project creation run ng serve to run the application .
o   Create angular 2 app (Intellij)
•   Add angular CLI plugin to your Intellij
•   File -> new ->static web-> Angular CLI . This will run the above mentioned commands to create angular 2 app

For commands related to angular CLI